# Workaround for error 10 $digest() iterations reached

Tags: angularjs

I am displaying data from the database (using Web API) on the page:

```
<div ng-repeat="Item in Items">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">{{Item.Id}}</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">{{Item.Desc)}}</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">{{Item.CollectionID}}</div>

    </div>
</div>
```

the above works fine, but when I try getting actual Collection Name, I get an issue:

```
<div ng-repeat="Item in Items">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">{{Item.Id}}</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">{{Item.Desc)}}</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">{{GetCollectionName(Item.CollectionID)}}</div>

    </div>
</div>
```

here is my controller function for getting Collection Name:

```
 $scope.GetCollectionName = function (CollId) {

      $http.get('http://Server/App/api/GetCollName/' + CollId).
      then(function (result) {
            $scope.CollectionName = result.data;
            return $scope.CollectionName;
       });
  }
```

is there a better way to do this besides modifying my underlying query?

Comment: The reason it's getting an infinite digest loop is because $http sets your $scope.CollectionName variable. Since a $scope variable changed, it triggers a DOM refresh for structural angular directives (ng-if, ng-repeat, etc.) Refreshing items in the ng-repeat then re-calls GetCollectionName() for each item, which then set a $scope variable, which then triggers a DOM refresh... you get the point. It goes on infinitely. $digest() has a default maximum of 10 successive iterations before it fails out so it doesn't lock your browser out due to infinite looping, which is the error you're seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea here is to use ng-init to initialize a **local** `CollectionName` variable for each Item in your `ng-repeat`. You can then use that local variable to output `CollectionName[Item.CollectionID]`.

[Here's a working demo](http://jsbin.com/rafutevivu/edit?html,js,output)

```
<div ng-repeat="Item in Items" ng-init="GetCollectionName(Item.CollectionID)">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">{{Item.Id}}</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">{{Item.Desc)}}</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">{{CollectionName[Item.CollectionID]}}</div>
    </div>
</div>


$scope.CollectionName = [];
$scope.GetCollectionName = function (CollId) {
    $http.get('http://Server/App/api/GetCollName/' + CollId)
    .then(function (result) {
        $scope.CollectionName[CollId] = result.data;
    });
}
```

Comment: the same thing happening

Comment: @ElenaDBA Make sure you do not have a reference to GetCollectionName() inside {{ }}. This code as is should not be creating an infinite digest loop

Comment: than I do not see how $scope.GetCollectionName gets called?

Comment: @ElenaDBA Look at the updated HTML with this example as well... That's exactly what  ng-init="GetCollectionName(Item.CollectionID)" does

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.GetCollectionName = function (CollId) {

  if(!$scope.someDataCheck[CollId] && !$scope.someData[CollId]){
$scope.someDataCheck[CollId] = true;
$http.get('http://Server/App/api/GetCollName/' + CollId).
  then(function (result) {
        $scope.someDataCheck[CollId] = false;
        $scope.someData[CollId].data = result.data;
   });
 }

  return $scope.someData[CollId];
}
```

Comment: This will return {} every time due to async nature

Comment: I don't think you understand the underlying problem with this approach.. The function will not wait for your $http call to finish before it executes the return statement unless you use $q or another deferred promise method

Comment: this will work. When scope changes, data will be rendered. May be here should be $scope.$apply in $timeout also

Comment: As of right now, I believe this solution will not work as you intend, but I could be wrong. Post an explanation & working demo with your code and I will remove downvote.

Comment: Explanation is simple. On first render it show empty string, yep. Just after request done, scope changes and !$scope.someData[CollId] return false, that prevent creation of another requests. And yep, you're right, here should be one another check that request already sended.

Comment: And I don't say that my answer is best practice, but it show how it can be done )

Comment: Yes, this is a rather bloated solution that pollutes the $scope with unnecessary flags, but I will remove my downvote since you added the someDataCheck which prevents the infinite digest loop and makes your code work

Comment: 1. In some cases on this flags you can set animations/other things.
2. If you copypaste your code  from one project to another, you can copy only one string.
3) In fact, firstly coder should generate array with ids, and then make only one large request
4) Laurianti's code provided higher will work, but my code will work with predefined values and without them.

Answer (score 0):

It is bad practice to call the function inside loop. And you are using expression tag in angularjs which creates watcher. Always make sure all the necessary records to display is already in the associated scope variable.